# extract mean of circle patche in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

i have some X/Y coordinates that represent the center of a circle somewhere in an image. From that circle, i want to compoute the mean of all the point contained inside the circle.

currently, i compute the mean of a square patche as follow, but a square is not relevent for the project. Ideally, i would like to do it only with numpy. but if it is not possible, i would concidere something else.

```
mean = np.mean(image[Y - margin : Y + margin, X - margin, X + margin])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a solution where I compute all indexes contained in a centered disk.

- I calculate the squarred euclidean distance of each X/Y coordinate of a squarre array.
- I compare it to the squarred radius of the circle.
- If it is superior, the point is not contained in the circle. Mark it as 0, 1 otherwise
- I extract indexes where the array is equal to one (disk-shaped)
- I center the computed indexes. To use them, i add the X/Y coordinate of a specific image point.

**NOTE**: I used the squarred euclidean distance because the square root function is monotonic (i.e constantly increasing). So, it saves compational power to keep with the squarred version.

```
radius = 4
size = 2 * radius + 1
radiusSquarred= radius**2
mask = np.zeros((size, size))
distance = lambda x, y: (x-radius)**2 + (y-radius)**2
for i in range(size):
    for j in range (2 * radius+ 1):
        if distance(i, j) <= radiusSquarred:
            mask[i, j] = 1
index = np.where(mask == 1)
diskIndexes = (index[0] - radius, index[1] - radius)

X, Y = 100, 150
np.mean(image[diskIndexes[0] + Y, diskIndexes[1] + X])
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood,

**YOU HAVE**: (x,y) of the center of the circle

**YOU WANT**: mean of all the points contained in the circle

Since all the points on the right side should be equal to the number of points on the left side of the center, **Wouldn't the mean be the same as the center of the circle !?**

Comment: You just said you've got a circle.
please attach an image for further explanation.

Comment: i meant the points inside the circle. Otherwise, the mean is indeed equal to the center. The same as the line of code i provided, but as a circle instead of a square